# angular.js slick carousel showing blank slides

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slick.js

I am using angular.js and making use of the slick carousel. I have about 9 items in the carousel, and have only slightly modified the styles (mainly moving the prev/next buttons around), and I am getting what looks like 4-5 blank slides [image]

Here is my slick config 
(coffeescript)

```
$scope.firstSlickConfig = {
      arrows: true
      slidesToShow: 5
      rows: 1
      draggable: false
      slidesToScroll: 1
      infinite: true
      dots: false
      variableWidth: true
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1450
          settings:
            slidesToShow: 1
            infinite: true
            slidesToScroll: 1
            slidesPerRow: 1
        }
        {
          breakpoint: 960
          settings:
            enabled: true
            draggable: true
            slidesToShow: 3
            slidesToScroll: 1
            rows: 1
            infinite: true
            arrows: true
        }
        {
          breakpoint: 786
          settings:
            enabled: true
            draggable: true
            slidesToShow: 2
            slidesToScroll: 1
            rows: 1
            infinite: true
            arrows: true
        }
        {
          breakpoint: 415
          settings:
            enabled: true
            draggable: true
            slidesToShow: 2
            slidesToScroll: 1
            rows: 1
            infinite: true
            arrows: true
            mobileFirst: true
        }
      ]
    }
```

does anyone know how I can get rid of these 'ghost' slides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found slick's angular docs (https://github.com/devmark/angular-slick-carousel) and saw an `event` function I can tie into. I have 9 placeholder elements, so I just put

```
event:
  afterChange: (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) ->
    if currentSlide == 8
      slick.slickGoTo(1)
    return
```

definitely dirty and wish it handled this better, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when I was working with the Slick slider not long ago and it can take a bit of fiddling around to get right.

If you have both

```
infinite: true
variableWidth: true
```

you may also want to add

```
  centerMode: true
  slidesToShow: 1
```

Which can help the slider recycle. Because you've got "Slides to show = 5" it will keep going to the end till 5 slides are showing. But if some of the slides are different widths AND you have it set as infinite the recycling can be an issue from my experience. Otherwise try turning Infinite off.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but unfortunately that didn't do much :(

Comment: Yeah it can take a bit of fiddling around with the settings to get right. I saw you had to add extra items to fix it, which is a bit annoying. If you like you could put it up on a jsfiddle or something and I could have a look over it better.

Comment: ya it is annoying. another issue which I have noticed from it, is I will adjust something and everything will break. For example, it seemed like it worked just fine earlier with the extra images, now it is broken again. It could be the width of my container it is placed in which is `1000px`+ wide, but it still isn't working correctly and now I have a giant empty area inside the carousel

Comment: would you happen to know a work around for this? Like a way I could think of would be after `n` number of elements for it to automatically reset, or on click just have it constantly shuffle back/forth between the elements. Maybe these could both work, but I'm not sure how to invoke other functions or what functions slick gives you access to.

Comment: The slider container should be automatically set to 100% by the Slick JS. I think depending on what parameters you use sometimes they can conflict with each other. Like my slides were different widths so the slider had issues recycling when I set it to infinite. But if you are showing say 4 slides and only cycling one slide at a time then it shouldn't have a problem, especially if the slides are all the same size. You may want to try a different slider perhaps, like http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html

Comment: I was looking at owl and really like it, but I actually figured it out. I have 9 (placeholder) elements in the carousel. I found slick has an `event` function you can tie into, and just put
      `event:
        afterChange: (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) ->
          if currentSlide == 8
            slick.slickGoTo(1)
          return`

Comment: Far out, it wasn't even in the Slick Documentation either! Well nice work figuring it out and getting it to work finally haha